# HTML5 Canvas rotate trouble

Tags: html5-canvas

I have a canvas element on which I am drawing a number of images and overlaying them with text.  Unfortunately the problem requires that some of these images and corresponding text be rotated.  Added to this the problem that there must be a corresponding background color on some of the images (images are simple outlines of desks for a floorplan)

Here is the function I have built to  handle adding a single desk to the plan.  The problem I am having is that when I use the rotate neither the text nor the background colors show up, while the appear correctly if I do not rotate the image, except that they are not rotated and the background fillRect() is oriented 90 degrees off.

```
function redrawDesk(desk, ctx, color) {
    var rotate = desk.rotation == 90 || desk.rotation == 270;
    if (rotate) {
        ctx.save();
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);

        ctx.clearRect(desk.left, desk.top, desk.width, desk.height);
        ctx.restore()
    }

    var img = $("#desk_" + desk.rowID)[0];
    ctx.drawImage(img, desk.left, desk.top, desk.height, desk.width);

    var x = desk.left;
    var y = desk.top;
    var h = desk.height;
    var w = desk.width;

    if (rotate) {
        //ctx.save()
        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / 2);
        var tmp=x;
        x=y;
        y=tmp;
        tmp=h;
        h=w;
        w=tmp;
    }        
    ctx.textAlign = "center";

    ctx.fillText(desk.deskID, x + w / 2,y + h/ 2);
    if (color) {
        ctx.fillStyle = color;
        ctx.fillRect(x, y, w, h);
    }
    //ctx.restore();
    if (rotate) {

        ctx.rotate(Math.PI / -2);
    }
}
```

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main problem is that you are defining the desk and text as absolute coordinates.

Define objects in there local coordinate system. Eg the desk has a height and width but not a position. Its draw relative to its self (around 0,0)

```
const desk = {
    w : 10, h : 10,
    color : "blue",
    draw() {
       ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
       ctx.fillRect(-this.w / 2, -this.h / 2, this.w, this.h);
    }
};
```

You can then position the desk into the world coordinate system (the canvas) by defining where its center will be.

```
function drawObj(obj, x, y) { // what to draw and where
    ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,x,y);  // Same as ctx.translate if 2D API is in default context
                                    // The means you do not have to use ctx.save and 
                                    // ctx.restore in this function
    obj.draw();  // draw desk
}
```

For a full transform its much the same

```
function drawObj(obj, x, y, scale, rotate) { // rotate is in radians
    ctx.setTransform(scale, 0, 0, scale, x, y);  
    ctx.rotate(rotate);
    obj.draw();  
}
```

To add text you can add it as an object to the desk and draw it to its own local coordinate system

```
desk.name = {
    text : "Desk",
    color : "black",
    font : "bold " + 20 + "px Calibri",
    draw() {  
        ctx.font = this.font;
        ctx.textAlign = "center";
        ctx.fillStyle = this.color;
        ctx.fillText(this.text, 0,0);
    }
};
```

You can now draw the desk and name using the draw object function

```
drawObj(desk,200, 200, 1, Math.PI / 2); // Draw at 200,200 rotated 90deg CW
drawObj(desk.name, 200, 200, 1, Math.PI / 2); // draw the text rotated same and centered over desk

// Or if the text should be above and not rotated
drawObj(desk.name, 200, 200 - 30, 1, 0);
```

As the above functions use `setTransform` you may need to restore the transform. There are two ways to do this.

```
ctx.resetTransform(); // Check browser support for this call

ctx.setTransform(1,0,0,1,0,0); // same as above just does it manaly
```

Answer (score 0):

In my code I tested to see if there is a rotation needed.  If so I set a translate on the canvas to give me a new start point: ctx.translate(x, y);  This allowed me to simplify my location settings for placing text and the background colors, which means they are showing up correctly.  Here is the changed code to compare with the original:

```
if (rotate) {
    ctx.save();
    tmp = h;
    h = w;
    w = tmp;
    ctx.translate(x, y);
}
if (color) {
    ctx.fillStyle = color;
    ctx.fillRect(0, 0, w, h);
}
ctx.font = "bold " + w / 2 + "px Calibri";
ctx.textAlign = "center";
ctx.fillStyle = "#000";
var c=ctx.canvas;
ctx.rotate(Math.PI / -2);
ctx.fillText(desk.deskID, 0-h/2, w/2); //x + w / 2, y + h / 2);
ctx.restore();
```